# Mac dictionary for python or other programming languages to documentation tooltip

Tags: python, macos

I was wondering whether Mac dictionaries (I am not sure about the format) exist for python help files? My idea is that simply using the three finger tap on the trackpad in my text editor brings up the dictionary popup and shows me the help for a python function. Wouldn't that be great! Any idea whether something like that exists?

Comment: Even if it doesn't exist you can always create one. You need to get the clipboard content(`selected python function`) and than you can get its corresponding documentation using `pydoc pythonfunc` and than display it in a `tkinker GUI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for context-sensitive help for Python, the [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) plugin for Eclipse does this when you hover:

[image]

Comment: That is my idea (I changed the title accordingly). I am not using Eclipse and my idea was that Mac OS X dictionaries could provide such tooltips independent of the actual text editor...

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is a stub, mostly to force myself to create a better answer.)

The Ruby community has both [ruby documentation](https://www.zenspider.com/ruby/2010/01/rdoc-via-osx-s-dictionary-app.html) and [rails documentation](https://github.com/priithaamer/railsdictionary) available for the macOS dictionary, so this sort of thing is definitely possible. (**NB**: those are both from 2010, and they may be wildly out of date.)

“How hard could it be,” he wondered, “to make the same for Python?” To be continued…